# Getting Error #1009: But Buttons Loaded on Movie Load?

Tags: actionscript-3

In my 1st frame I have the following action script and it works fine.

```
cal.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(){gotoAndStop( "cal" )});
trucks.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(){gotoAndStop( "truck" )});
raven.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(){gotoAndStop( "raven" )});
frank.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(){gotoAndStop( "fr" )});
Pool.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(){gotoAndStop( "pool" )});
school.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(){gotoAndStop( "sch" )});
wti.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(){gotoAndStop( "wti" )});
```

But after any of these buttons are clicked and from the other frame (cal, pool etc) I try to return to this home frame I get

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
```

This error points to the first line of that code above. So I comment it out and it points to the next and so on.

I don't understand why it works when the movie loads but not when trying to return to this home frame.

--- Update ----

Still looking into this - tried the other way of doing it proposed & no luck. If there is a better way to do it can someone please tell me what it is - I typically work on the design side and am not really very good at as3 but want to get there!!! 
Thanks!!

Thank you in advance for ANY help!! I'm stumped!!

--- Update ---
I've posted a lot of code below. It still loads / traces fine on frame 1. On other frames only the last two come up in a trace (though they should all be the same). Then when returning to frame 1 they are all null.

If there is a better way to do this / even if it means doing it totally differently I'd appreciate the direction.

TY

Comment: Have you imported MouseEvent? is `cal`, `trucks` etc defined? Have you named the frames "cal", "truck" etc?

Comment: Im sorry I didn't see this Pranav.
I have created buttons, given them instance names that match the code and have exported them for actionscript. on Frame 1 all of the buttons are traced but when I leave frame 1 I start to get erros & when I return to it I get errors.  So far only the last two are showing up when I trace it - I don't understand this because I built them all the same.  Here is an example of the code on a different frame

Comment: stop()


RMSt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, RMStFunction);
function RMStFunction(event: MouseEvent) {
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("URL GOES HERE);
navigateToURL(request, "_blank");
}

home.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent){gotoAndPlay( "home" )});


trace(cal)
trace(trucks)
trace(raven)
trace(frank)
trace(Pool)
trace(school)
trace(wti)

Comment: cal.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent){gotoAndStop( "cal" )});
trucks.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent){gotoAndStop( "truck" )});
raven.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent){gotoAndStop( "raven" )});
frank.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent){gotoAndStop( "fr" )});
Pool.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent){gotoAndStop( "pool" )});
school.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent){gotoAndStop( "sch" )});

Comment: wti.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent){gotoAndStop( "wti" )});

Answer (score 0):

it should be `cal.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent){gotoAndStop( "cal" )});`, but the way you are doing it isn't very efficient

Comment: what would be efficient? I'd love to learn a better way!  - Update - I just tried this & it gave me the same error.

Comment: is the `cal` movie clip defined? Try a `trace(cal)` above all the event listeners.

Comment: On initial load it traces [object Calverton] but when you go back to that frame it comes up null

Comment: OK- I've traced cal on both the 1st frame - fine. Then again on a different frame & it comes up null even though it's in the frame & has that instance name. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have added traces for the other items- when seeing some stuff off I copied & pasted the buttons into the other frames to insure that all was the same. I now see -when tracing - all nulls but the last two buttons. Any thoughts?